# Can't boot to Ubuntu after installing it with Wubi

Tags: installation, wubi, ssd

Hi I'm trying to install Ubuntu using Wubi, but when I reboot I press <kbd>esc</kbd> for advanced options, selected verbose mode it stops here

[image]

My hardware is: Intel dp67bg motherboard, Intel 2600k CPU, and the Windows/Wubi installation is on a GSkill phoenix Pro SSD.

Does any one knows what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your computer detects a Nvidia graphics card and attempts to load the open-source nouveau drivers, if that is not working for you you need to disable those at boot.

Edit the file `\ubuntu\install\wubildr-disk.cfg` where you installed Wubi to and open that file with a text editor, look down to the line with *quiet splash* and in front of *splash* add *nomodeset*.

It should read then ***quiet splash nomodeset***.

Save the file and reboot.

Comment: Wubi-specific instructions for nomodeset: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10089820&postcount=8

Comment: @bcbc thx for the heads up!

Comment: ok it seems to go a bir further, now i get a ubuntu loading screen for like one sec and then http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12155010/28012012031.jpg

Comment: It looks like it's having a prob. mounting /dev/sda1. Is this Ubuntu 11.10 or a different flavour: Kubuntu/Mythbuntu? Can you boot a live CD and run the bootinfoscript and attach a link to your post: http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Comment: nevermind about the previous comment, i had my cellphone connected by USB it was messing up the drives....

Comment: it seems to work now :) thank you very mutch
@Bruno muito obrigado :)